# How to configure Apache 2 to use a proxy server for external HTTPS request?

Tags: apache, https, http-proxy, mod-proxy

My requirement is to hit external HTTPS REST API from application server.i don`t have internet access in application server(JBOSS). so,i forwarded my request to web server(Apache24) and from web server i am calling HTTPS REST API services.

```
Public Rest URL-: https://publicdomain.com/tracking_number
```

I made below configuration on Apache server.

```
ProxyPass       /tracking_number https://publicdomain.com/tracking_number
ProxyPassReverse       /tracking_number https://publicdomain.com/tracking_number
```

With above configuration,following URL from application server **https://WEBSERVER_IP:PORT/tracking_number**, responding 503 proxy error.
Because in web server, internet can be access only through proxy server.
(For example, In IE browsers,if i configure proxy ip and host in LAN settings mean, URL is accessible from browser).

So, i need to configure similar configuration in Apache also. I tried with some configurations with help of http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyremote. But nothing worked out.

How to configure proxy server(host and ip) for external HTTPS request in Apache.

Apache Version -: 2.4.29
Operating System -: Windows

Comment: You want to have a proxy between your proxy and the webserver? I'd say: Put the httpd-proxy somewhere where it has access to the proxied webserver. It's intranet setups that require proxy access for outgoing connections from browsers, but that shouldn't matter for server-to-server connections. Also, this looks like a bad fit for stackoverflow - check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Olaf Kock I want to have a proxy between the web server and https rest api service.